# read Java public variables as keys from map

Tags: java, hashmap

I had a static class that contained several static variables:

```
public class A{
static {
}   
public static final String param1= "paramVal1"; 
public static final String param2= "paramVal2";
}
```

I want to change the code, so that the variables will be in a map:

```
public class A{
static {
}
private static Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>() ;
    public static void initParams() {
    params.put("param1", paramVal1);
    params.put("param2", paramVal2);
}
```

However, I already have many classes that call those public parameters, and I don't want to go to every class and change it. Is there any way to use some define function, that would cause java to return the map's value, when the parameter is called? i.e if someone calls A.param1, it would return params.get("param1")

Comment: i guess not. what you can atleast do is create a helper class with the hashmap impl in it and go to each class manually and change it.

Comment: If I go to each class manually and change it, I can just use the hashmap from this class. What is the advantage of creating a helper class?

Comment: well this is my only reason - reusability, component based architecture which is the essence of OO.

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this in the first place? Having constant fields makes client code safer and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter in not as easy to use (and overwrite) than a method. So I think that short answer to your question is *no*. That's one of the reasons of getters and setters. But you can allways do the inverse, that is keep the old parameters for compatibility and use a map for newer uses :

```
public class A{
    static {
        param1 = "paramVal1";
        param2 = "paramVal2";
        params = new HashMap<String, String>;
        params.put("param1", param1);
        params.put("param2", param2);
        // eventually other inits for params
    }   
    public static final String param1= "paramVal1"; 
    public static final String param2= "paramVal2";
    public static Map<String, String params;
    /* or better private static Map<String,String> params
       and access via getter */

    public static getParam(String name) {
        return param.get(name);
    }
}
```

That way, old classes could allways do `A.param1`, and for newer classes you could start using `A.get("param1")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public class A {
  private static Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

  static {
    params.put("param1", "paramVal1");
    params.put("param2", "paramVal2");
  }   

  public static final String param1 = params.get("param1"); 
  public static final String param2 = params.get("param2");
}
```